# How to hot swap a jsp file in weblogic server

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic

Currently I have my weblogic server for my local set to nostage. I read that this would enable me to make hotswaps to jsp files but I am not seeing any change when even after I clear the cache. I don't want to have to bounce my server everytime I want a simple html change to be made. Any ideas on how to make a hot swap in weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

Undeploy your component, delete all cache/temp data dir and try to deploy your component in command line with the appropriate flag :

```
java weblogic.Deployer  -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic
   -password weblogic -name mydeploymentname 
   -targets myserver -nostage 
   -deploy c:\localfiles\myapp.ear
```

and don't forget to set the CLASSPATH with the weblogic.jar before in this way  :

```
SET CLASSPATH=yourWeblogicServer\server\lib\weblogic.jar
```

Else, for hot swapping, you have another alternative : use the Eclipse WTP plugin to deploy your component.

And the last alternative if you don't deploy EAR is using a servlet container like Tomcat when you are are working on the web part of the application.
You will gain much time with it.